# How to create an unlimited depth category subcategory select box in smarty

Tags: tree, smarty

I am trying to create a select box containing unlimited depth category , sub category select box. I have an array contains the unlimited category sub category depth as shown below,

```
                    Array
                    (
                        [0] => Array
                            (
                                [id] => 6
                                [cata_key] => 32e9c75e38d2a1d77b2b49b2
                                [cata_name] => Road
                                [app_key] => b80e0935b348da61b2a807ff
                                [parentid] => 0
                                [subcategories] => Array
                                    (
                                        [0] => Array
                                            (
                                                [id] => 9
                                                [cata_key] => 780c3eb53264d5c33a26d49f
                                                [cata_name] => Cars
                                                [app_key] => b80e0935b348da61b2a807ff
                                                [parentid] => 6
                                                [subcategories] => Array
                                                    (
                                                        [0] => Array
                                                            (
                                                                [id] => 10
                                                                [cata_key] => 111cd06b1575457f665d460e
                                                                [cata_name] => Hyundai
                                                                [app_key] => b80e0935b348da61b2a807ff
                                                                [parentid] => 9
                                                                [subcategories] => Array
                                                                    (
                                                                    )

                                                            )

                                                        [1] => Array
                                                            (
                                                                [id] => 11
                                                                [cata_key] => 26ca0e1622c11ed2628eaadf
                                                                [cata_name] => Maruthi
                                                                [app_key] => b80e0935b348da61b2a807ff
                                                                [parentid] => 9
                                                                [subcategories] => Array
                                                                    (
                                                                    )

                                                            )

                                                    )

                                            )

                                        [1] => Array
                                            (
                                                [id] => 16
                                                [cata_key] => 49973084640af71ad61e634b
                                                [cata_name] => Bikes
                                                [app_key] => b80e0935b348da61b2a807ff
                                                [parentid] => 6
                                                [subcategories] => Array
                                                    (
                                                    )

                                            )

                                    )

                            )

                        [1] => Array
                            (
                                [id] => 7
                                [cata_key] => 56bae4297efcbf796b230a99
                                [cata_name] => River
                                [app_key] => b80e0935b348da61b2a807ff
                                [parentid] => 0
                                [subcategories] => Array
                                    (
                                        [0] => Array
                                            (
                                                [id] => 12
                                                [cata_key] => 7fc72e49fe67d0b777648f54
                                                [cata_name] => Boat
                                                [app_key] => b80e0935b348da61b2a807ff
                                                [parentid] => 7
                                                [subcategories] => Array
                                                    (
                                                        [0] => Array
                                                            (
                                                                [id] => 14
                                                                [cata_key] => 38c749056a9f583e284e509b
                                                                [cata_name] => 2 Seater
                                                                [app_key] => b80e0935b348da61b2a807ff
                                                                [parentid] => 12
                                                                [subcategories] => Array
                                                                    (
                                                                    )

                                                            )

                                                        [1] => Array
                                                            (
                                                                [id] => 15
                                                                [cata_key] => 6ebfcad4d4e05e84d333b7e5
                                                                [cata_name] => 10 Seater
                                                                [app_key] => b80e0935b348da61b2a807ff
                                                                [parentid] => 12
                                                                [subcategories] => Array
                                                                    (
                                                                    )

                                                            )

                                                    )

                                            )

                                        [1] => Array
                                            (
                                                [id] => 13
                                                [cata_key] => b6125c73f6d7c153f45e133e
                                                [cata_name] => Ship
                                                [app_key] => b80e0935b348da61b2a807ff
                                                [parentid] => 7
                                                [subcategories] => Array
                                                    (
                                                    )

                                            )

                                    )

                            )

                        [2] => Array
                            (
                                [id] => 8
                                [cata_key] => 1c748603f36105b921b54165
                                [cata_name] => Air
                                [app_key] => b80e0935b348da61b2a807ff
                                [parentid] => 0
                                [subcategories] => Array
                                    (
                                    )

                            )

                    )
```

I would like to create a select box in tpl for the visitor to select proper category / sub category. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

You can use Smarty 3 and [functions](http://www.smarty.net/docs/en/language.function.function.tpl)
In your case

PHP:

```
$smarty->assign("you_category_array", **$you_array**);
```

Smarty:

```
{function name=menu level=0}
  <ul class="level{$level}">
  {foreach $data as $category}
    {if is_array($category.subcategories)}
      <li>{$category.cata_name}
      {menu data=$category.subcategories level=$level+1}</li>
    {else}
      <li>{$category.cata_name}</li>
    {/if}
  {/foreach}
  </ul>
{/function}

{menu data=$you_category_array}
```